# Resource file code not generated

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, user-interface, localization

I have my default resource file `Resources.resx` for which visual studio nicely generates a `designer.cs` class, but when I try to create `Resources.de-DE.resx`, it does not generate.

I checked all the properties for both files are same.

It does generate for `Resources1.resx`,  but not for `Resources.de-DE.resx` or `Resources.en-US.resx`.

Comment: designer.cs *isn't* created by the resx, its created by visual studio along with the class file for the dialog (user control). What are you trying to accomplish? When the program runs, it will look for the correct string in the local resx, if it fails, it will look in the default resx

Comment: I have a same problem. If I create the Resources.resx, code in Resources.Designer.resx generates. But, if rename file first file to Resources.en.resx, it doesn't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hello @TRS you may be confused about that there is a **Designer.cs** present For **Resources.resx** and there should be **someDesigner.cs** for **Resources.de-DE.resx** but this is not the case because designer file would be same for all the resource files. and also the property that is created in **Designer.cs** is also common that means you will use this property for every conversion so the difference that you can make is on the basis of  ResourceCulture.

Comment: This helped me find out why I didn't have a resource-class when I didn't provide a default resource file.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Designer resx file remains empty.
you should follow the below steps, it will work 100%.
1) Create Resource.resx file under any folder

2) set CustomTools = PublicResXFileCodeGenerator and
Build Action = Embedded Resource in Resource.resx file property.

3) Now create the different language files like below,
Resources.en-US.resx
Resources.nl-NL.resx  etc

4)If MVC, in your MVC Model refer this namespace as project.folder

5) change the one of the property as below (example)

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}"), Display(Name = "dtMovinDate",ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resource))]
            public DateTime dtMovinDate { get; set; }
```

6)

```
 In config file add this under System.web

    <globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

7) rebuild the project and test it.

It will work. The real reason of designer.cs file empty is resource designer.cs will refer these files based on your web.config file.

Comment: Step 2 solved my problem as the key values of the resource file were not accessible in the asp.net pages and now they are acessible. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, I had similar situation today. I will share the scenario and solution here because I think it's related to your question.

I wanted to have a resource file for Arabic culture only, `SharedResources.ar.resx`, and I don't have another resource called `SharedResources.resx`.

The solution was to create the resource file with single [dot] in it, then rename it.

For example, in my case, I created the file with this name, `SharedResources-ar.resx`. Then double click and change its access modifier to public using the editor, like this:

[image]

This will generate .cs file with the correct static properties. 
After that, rename the file to the correct format. `SharedResources.ar.resx`. Otherwise it will not be generated!

I don't know if it's a good solution, but solve my problem and hope to solve someone's else too.